# Verlog delays modeling

Tags: if-statement, verilog, delay, nonblocking

Example code below.

I have always with if\else. Each portion has its own delay - X\Y.
My problem is whether circuit enters the 'if' and start to calculate 'X' delay and then asynchronous event enters 'else' it still remembers the 'X' delay instead of calculate 'Y' delay. ['X' >> 'Y']
The 'if' and 'else' portions working on the same signals [sigA below].

My question, how to verify the asynchronous event clears delay 'X' and starts the 'else' operation from delay 'Y'?
Tried also blocking assigments and another hardware tricks [MUX at the out]. But simulator only remembers the long delay.
I am trying to avoid overkill design such a logic always [always *] and a counting state machine but using the delay operator.

Thanks.

```
always @(event)
begin
   if (event)
     /#X;
     sigA <= value1;
   end //end if
   else
     begin
     /#Y;
     sigA <= value2;
   end //else
end //always***
```

Comment: Is that really part of your code? Because that won't even compile! Your if statement has 'end' but no 'begin'. And what is the '/' before '#' ?

Comment: No its not, i tried to sustain a working verilog code but obviously its after compilation. Sorry for confuse.

Comment: OK. Your question is ambiguous but the answer may be in using intra-assignment delay i.e. sigA <= #X value1;

Comment: It would help to show an example of expected behavior. Also, is this design to be synthesized ?

Answer (score 0):

if verilog hits a delay in an always block, it will stop execution of it and will not attempt any new execution of it till the delay is cleared.

So, your 'else' part can only be executed after the delay in the 'then' part is cleared.

Here is an example for experimenting

```
module a;

   reg [3:0] v1, v2;
   reg       clk;
   integer   i ;


   initial begin #7 v1 = 1; end


   initial begin
  $display ("hello");
  clk = 0;

  v1 = 0;
  v2 = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    #2 clk = ~clk;

  $finish;

   end

   always @(clk)
 begin
    $display ("%3t starting the block, clk=%b", $time, clk);
    if (v1)
      begin
     #6 v1 = ~v1;
     $display ("%3t assignment is done", $time);

      end
    else
      begin
     $display ("%3t else hello", $time);         
     #12 v1 = ~v2;
     $display ("%3t else is done", $time);

      end
 end // always @ (clk)
endmodule // a
```

and the result:

```
$ ./a
 hello
   0 starting the block, clk=0
   0 else hello
  12 else is done
  12 starting the block, clk=0
  18 assignment is done
  18 starting the block, clk=1
  18 else hello
  30 else is done
  30 starting the block, clk=1
  36 assignment is done
  36 starting the block, clk=0
  36 else hello$ ./a
```